# Bug in libstdc++ regarding std::list assignment?

Tags: c++, list, gcc, c++11, std

I've recently came across a very interesting inconsistency while using libxml++ (a C++ wrapper for libxml2).

The library returns node lists using default STL list container (`std::list<xmlpp::Node*>`).
Since it is installed from default repositories, it seems to be built in C++03 mode (but I'm working with C++11).

The caveat here is that C++11 changed the way `std::list::size()` works.
In C++03 it was O(n), calling `std::distance(begin(), end())` each time - and now it returns the pre-computed value.

Here is the code:

```
  /**  Returns the number of elements in the %list.  */
  size_type
  size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  {
#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
    return this->_M_impl._M_size;
#else
    return std::distance(begin(), end());
#endif
  }
```

Things begin to happen when I receive such a list from the library and call `size()` on it. There I read values like 140734320138496, which clearly indicate an uninitialized counter: in original list there was no counter altogether.
Manually calling `std::distance (list.begin(), list.end())` does work, of course.

The question is - can this be considered a bug in GCC/libstdc++ or I should never link executables built in different GCC modes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's a violation of the One Definition Rule. Your code is compiled with a different definition of `std::list` than what your library is using. (This is undefined behavior, not a GCC bug.)

You should recompile your library (or recompile your code).